# Modifying Grid Height/Width

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am working on a project that is a world planner/builder for a game that I enjoy. I want to make the grid 100 * 54. I have been messing around with some code on JSFiddle and I can't seem to get what I want. I would like the size of the grid squares to be 16*16

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  selection: false
});
var grid = 50;


// create grid

for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  }))
}

// add objects

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: '#faa',
  lockRotation: true,
  lockScalingX: true,
  lockScalingY: true,
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true,
  hasControls: false
}));


// snap to grid

canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
  options.target.set({
    left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
    top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
  });
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way this works:
Grid is how big your grid will be in pixels.
You need two for loops to indicate how many lines for each.
The for loops generate the grid based on how many loops it goes through. (so 54 means 54 lines.)

The 2000 indicates how long the line will be in pixels.

Working code:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  selection: false
});
var grid = 16;


// create grid

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([i * grid, 0, i * grid, 2000], {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  })); // horizontal
}

for (var i = 0; i < 54; i++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, i * grid, 2000, i * grid], {
    stroke: '#ccc',
    selectable: false
  })); // vertical
}

// add objects

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 16,
  top: 16,
  width: 16,
  height: 16,
  fill: '#faa',
  lockRotation: true,
  lockScalingX: true,
  lockScalingY: true,
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true,
  hasControls: false
}));

// add objects

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 16,
  top: 16,
  width: 16,
  height: 16,
  fill: '#faa',
  lockRotation: true,
  lockScalingX: true,
  lockScalingY: true,
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true,
  hasControls: false
}));

// snap to grid

canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
  options.target.set({
    left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
    top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
  });
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="1600px" height="865px" ></canvas>
```